# Django channels Add users to group

Tags: django, django-channels

I'm using django channels I'm making a Facebook clone and trying to add real time notifications using channel, so I've this idea when a notification happens i create a group and add the users the one who sent it and the one who received it and after receiving it, then the group gets discarded, can this be accomplished?

Comment: Sure you can create a group, send a message and discard it, but why do you need to add the sender to the group? Why not just send to the receiver?

Comment: Maybe it was a weird way of thinking as it was my second time to use channels but i did it finally, every user connected has a group of his own, when a notify happens it's sent to this group and that's it

Comment: Yes, that's a good way to do it. I used the same in my project